# Zend Framework , Model Class not found in Module

Tags: zend-framework

I've Created an application with these details :

1- zf create project MyApp

2- zf create module admin

3- zf create controller Index 1 admin

MyApp/application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php :

```
class admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        $aa = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Posts();

    }

}
```

application.ini :

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0 
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library" 
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap" 
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

MyApp/application/modules/admin/models/DbTable/Posts.php :

```
class Admin_Model_DbTable_Posts extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract    
{
    public function init()
    {

    }
}
```

In this point I get the error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_DbTable_Posts' not found in /var/www/MyApp/application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php on line 16
```

and When i put this line on application.ini

```
resources.modules[] =
```

And add bootstratp.php in admin folder with these content

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

}
```

After a long period of requesting , i get this error :

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

what should i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem by putting together shawndreck and RokyFord answers . thanks to both of theme . I actually over configed application.ini file . I did the following :

I have Recreated another simple project and it work fine so i compare two project files.

Then i understand that with changing

> Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap

to

> Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap

and putting resources.modules[] = "admin" in the application.ini , it works .

- Some times **OVER CONFINING** the application.ini cause a lot of problems in Zend-Framework -at least for me, this happen alot-.

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful tips for you

- Explicitly load the modules in the application.ini with :

```
    resources.modules[] = "admin"
    resources.modules[] = "default"
```

- Make sure that you use double quotation `"` and not single quotation `'`for string literals in your application.ini file.
- If `Admin_Model_DbTable_Posts` is not found then the zend_autoloader or the include path is not complete. You can set the zend autoloader to use the fall back option  with the following code inside the Bootstrap.ini

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace(array('Admin_'));
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
    $autoloader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);   
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: any additional line to appication.ini begin with resources.modules[] cause some kind of loop result in "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)" , I don't know why ? and in /var/apache2/error.log is empty !

Comment: this is very strange! Which URL(s) result in this strange behavior. I want to think that perhaps `.htaccess` has something to do with it. By the way, what do you mean by"kind of loop"?

Comment: mydomain.com/admin return this result. I should said it send request and it take too long , instead of loop .

Comment: just in any case, what is in your main .htaccess file? This is particularly strange that no log remains of this error.Still trying to  think of something!

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not htaccess problems .

Answer (score 1):

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

}
```

should be

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Using **Module_Bootstrap** should work to provide module assets to your application. I wouldn't make any other changes.

Ignore the previous answer, good advice if you are using none standard setup, but your setup is apparently standard. You may have to capitalize *admin* in admin_IndexController, but maybe not.

Comment: thank's, i get ride of the annoying error 500 , but i stuck in the Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_DbTable_Posts' not found in /var/www/MyApp/application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php on line 18