# error not found model after upload into hosting

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, web-hosting

In localhost, it works fine. After uploading into my hosting i got this error. I'm using zend framework 1.12.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_DBTable_Kereta' not found in /home/mysite/public_html/application/controllers/CarController.php
```

others post said the problem is because the case sensitivity of file names. But i tried to change and nothing happens. See my attachment for the structured of my project. The attachment shown application and model names. 
[image]

edited : This problem occurs to all my models class.. can't find models..

Controller code :

```
class CarController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{  

   public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
        //klu login sbgai admin, papar layout admin, klu login sbgai user,     papar layout user laaaa, 
        Zend_Session::start();//start session
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace("MyNamespace");
        $id_pengguna = $session->id_pengguna;
        $kategori = $session->kategori;
        if($kategori==3)
        {

            $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layoutadmin');
        }
        else
        {
        }

}

public function indexAction()
{
   // $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
    //$this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();
}






public function reservationAction()
{

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        $jadual_tarikhmula  = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_tarikhmula");
        $jadual_tarikhtamat = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_tarikhtamat");
        $jadual_masamula1   = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_masamula1");
        $jadual_masamula2   = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_masamula2");
        $jadual_masatamat1  = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_masatamat1");
        $jadual_masatamat2  = $this->getRequest()->getPost("jadual_masatamat2");

        $simpan             = array($jadual_tarikhmula,$jadual_tarikhmula,$jadual_masamula1,$jadual_masatamat1);

        $papar              = $this->view->dataReserve= $simpan;
        $db                 = new Application_Model_DbTable_Kereta();





        $paparkereta        = $this->view->reserve      = $db->getReservationCar($jadual_tarikhmula,$jadual_tarikhmula,$jadual_masamula1,$jadual_masatamat1);


        $this->view->dataWujud = count($paparkereta);

        $gambar             = $this->view->gambarKereta = $db->getGambarKereta($paparkereta[0]['id_kereta'],false);



    }

}



}
```

Comment: you are using 'DBTable' while you namespace name is 'DbTable'

Comment: i already change name to DbTable but nothing changes..

Comment: You can add the namespace in config file and try again and make sure the class name is Kereta as well

Comment: oh man, don't know to add in config file.. any example?

Comment: use the class names as given below. REmove the Application from the beginging of the class name
class Model_DbTable_Kereta extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Comment: can you show me the application path from the index.php

Comment: nothing changes.. :( .. this is my index.. http://thunderwide.com/public/index .. try use the check availability form..

Comment: There is one magic button have you tried that ctrl+f5

Comment: what u mean?? refresh??

Comment: Yes.If you are using chrome ,It gets the cached page rather than fresh page.

Comment: i try pressing button, so?

Comment: can u paste the controller code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069299/zend-framework-model-class-not-found-in-module

Comment: edited already in post

Comment: why you using the word Application before the model clas

Comment: i see the documentation and it work fine at localhost,is it no need to put word application??

Comment: thank u mate.. problem solved. ijust need to change DBTable into DbTable. and in application.ini just need to change appnamespace = "Application_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder name is `DbTable` and your model class name is `..._DBTable_...` ?

Note that Linux is case-sensitive directory or filename.

And did you add this line to `.ini` file?

```
Appnamespace = "Application"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have another class named `Kereta` in `/home/mysite/public_html/application/controllers/CarController.php` ?

Also, consider cleaning the symfony cache with `symfony cc`. It's the cache for autoload that is giving you this error I guess.

Comment: It's a command you have to do at your project root directory :
`cd carrental`
`php symfony cc`
See http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/22?orm=Doctrine

Comment: Yes, open your console, do a `dir path\to\carrental`. Then do the `php.exe symfony cc`

Comment: php.exe not recognized

Comment: `c:\> php lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\symfony cc` ?